# how to see the configuration changes in jenkins for a particular job

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which was failing due to artifact issue :

`Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing artifact to Artifactory:`

My onsite lead has resolved the issue but she did not told me the steps/changes .

So my concern is , chow can I see the changes she made to the job.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most of the CI tools have this option to see the changes. Jenkins too has this support.

You can install the plugin ***Job Configuration History Plugin*** , so that for every change, you can have a track.

Answer (score 13):

Add "**Job Configuration History Plugin**" for tracking the changes done in configuration. Once added it will appear on left side, please refer below image.

[image]

Link to Plugin : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin

Also you can revert back to old configuration using this same Plugin.